# How do you use a variable in a regular expression and manipulate the variable?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I would like to create a replace function using *RegExp*. so far I've done something like this.

```
var re = new RegExp(FullName);
testBox2.value = testBox2.value.replace(/re.{13}/g," ");
```

so basically I wanted to pass the `FullName` and then using that full name want to delete the `fullName` and 13 characters after the `fullName`. But this code didn't seem to work.

previously I have done this, which worked perfectly.

```
testBox.value =  testBox.value.replace(FullName," ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `new` keyword like this when you want to use variables in a regular expression:

```
const stringToReplace = 'NameHere';
const regex = new RegExp(`${stringToReplace}.{13}`,'g');
```

Full working example:

```
const string = 'LeaveThisBitNameHereExtraStuffToo123'; 
const stringToReplace = 'NameHere'; 
const regex = new RegExp(`${stringToReplace}.{13}`,'g'); 
const res = string.replace(regex, ''); 
console.log(res); // -> LeaveThisBit123
```

Comment: Exactly where you want me to use the new?? I have already using new like ```var re = new RegExp(FullName); ``` here. Where else do I have to add New??

Comment: I've updated the answer above to give a full working example.

Comment: I also need to add some code to tell replace the 13 characters after the "fullName" too, where should I add this??

Comment: Would ````str.replace(regex, '');```` be ````string.replace(regex, '');```` instead as that's the variable name?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a util function to compose regular expressions:

```
function composeRegexp(a, b) {
    if (a instanceof RegExp) {
      a = a.toString().replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    if (b instanceof RegExp) {
      b = b.toString().replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    return new RegExp(a + b);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
const composed = composeRegexp(FullName, '.{13}');
```

Example:

```js
function composeRegexp(a, b) {
  if (a instanceof RegExp) {
    a = a.toString().replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
  }
  if (b instanceof RegExp) {
    b = b.toString().replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
  }
  return new RegExp(a + b);
}

const composed = composeRegexp(new RegExp('a'), '{3}');

console.log(composed.test('aaa'));
console.log(composed.test('abc'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an input text box (and an output box for testing):

```
<input id="testBox2" type="text" value="Hello Joe Bloggs, how are you doing today?"/>

<div id="output">result</div>
```

We can access both those elements with javascript:

```
var testBox2 = document.getElementById('testBox2');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
```

Then we can replace any specified fullName and the 13 characters after it like this:

```
var fullName = 'Joe Bloggs';

var regex = new RegExp(fullName+'.{13}', 'ig');
output.innerHTML = testBox2.value.replace(regex, '');
```

Here's the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/4whb9mc1/37/